# Dynamic type inference with TypeScript types/interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function with a return type, `UnpackedValuesOnly`, that can dynamically determine the type of a "packed" value `K` without the user having to explicitly define what `K` is.

Here's as close as I've been able to come:

```js
//pretend that this is a useful class for some reason
class PackedValue<T> {
  value: T
  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value
  }
}

//This is my best attempt at dynamically unpacking the type of a PackedValue
type UnpackedValuesOnly<T, K = any, K2 = any, K3 = any, K4 = any, K5 = any> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends PackedValue<K>
    ? K
    : T[P] extends PackedValue<K2>
    ? K2
    : T[P] extends PackedValue<K3>
    ? K3
    : T[P] extends PackedValue<K4>
    ? K4
    : T[P] extends PackedValue<K5>
    ? K5
    : UnpackedValuesOnly<T[P], K, K2, K3, K4, K5>
}

const unpackObj = <T, K = any, K2 = any, K3 = any, K4 = any, K5 = any>(toUnpack: T): UnpackedValuesOnly<T, K, K2, K3, K4, K5> => {
  //implementation unimportant, assume that non packed values are preserved, packed values are unpacked
  return {} as any as UnpackedValuesOnly<T, K, K2, K3, K4, K5>
}


const foo = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: new PackedValue([ 1, 3 ]),
  c: new PackedValue('asdf')
}

const bar =  unpackObj<typeof foo, number[]>(foo)

//type of string
bar.a

//type of number[]
bar.b

//type of any
bar.c
```

The above has a few major downsides:

1. There are a finite amount of `PackedValue` types allowed, in this case 5
2. The user must explicitly define all used `PackValue` types when calling `unpackObj` or those types will appear as an `any` type and lose all compiler checking

Is there a way of writing `UnpackedValuesOnly` so that the below example code will allow the compiler/linter to report the correct types by implicitly determining the type of `PackedValue`?

```js
const bar = unpackObj(foo) // or maybe unpackObj<typeof foo>(foo)

//type of string
bar.a

//type of number[]
bar.b

//type of string
bar.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way using `infer` keyword:

```
type UnpackedValueOnly<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends PackedValue<infer U> ? U : T[key]
}
```

Check this [TS sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKbANYFMAmA1MICuyA8AKgHzQDeAUNNAG5a4Bc0Bl0wA9gHYQAuATtsG5teAClo5kjAgEoyLKtwAWASwgA6cbmgBeGnWQsAvuWPluATwAOyaAFUOlhCgz6A8hxDnCJXRSpUAbRRzaGUOaGC2ADMmAF0pIORzWOhkAA9uZA5UGHgkNEwJPDCo5F47EgB%20O2gE4NiTcnJ2Lm5oKLY2HTkqMEYAckVkEBA2foAaFgAjRg5kAHc4JwL9EQDoAEZx6ABmaFjpSapgWYWl-JcJEX7IVCj%206UazKxsCZB5u%200cLwtx3TzwFms0XanSIQA) and hover over the `Test` to see that the initial type of the variable `foo` was

```
{
  a: string
  b: PackedValue<number[]>
  c: PackedValue<string>
}
```

And after unpacking it is

```
{
  a: string
  b: number[]
  c: string
}
```